# Python unittest Mock an object to not have an attribute

Tags: python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I have a function that runs some code if the object has a certain attribute, and in rare cases if if the object does not have the attribute, it runs different code. It is hard for me to create the object without the attribute for testing. I tried `del instance.attribute` but got an error. The attribute is actually a `@property` under the hood.

I have an object `instance` that has `foo` attribute. How does one mock it so that when one tries to access `instance.foo` it raises an `AttributeError` as usual if there is no attribute?

I tried `mock.Mock(side_effect=AttributeError('Boom!'))` but it only works with methods.

Comment: Use a [PropertyMock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html?highlight=patch#unittest.mock.PropertyMock) instead of a `Mock`.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Thats great for properties in general. The documentation has `mock_foo.return_value = 'mockity-mock'`, thats great for a static value, not sure how one would use it with a callable to raise an `AttributeError`

Comment: I'm adding a simple example as an answer (too inconvenient in a comment). Not sure if that is sufficient for your need - if not, you may want to adapt your question with some example code to show your use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use a [PropertyMock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html?highlight=patch#unittest.mock.PropertyMock) for the property, and generally you shall be able to set the respective side effect. Here is a simple working example:

```py
from unittest import mock
import pytest

class Foo:
    @property
    def bar(self):
        return "bar"


def test_no_foo():
    bar_mock = mock.PropertyMock()
    with mock.patch(f"{__name__}.Foo.bar", bar_mock):
        bar_mock.side_effect = AttributeError('Boom!')
        foo = Foo()
        with pytest.raises(AttributeError):
            foo.bar
```

As you patch the property in the class, not in the object, you can can also do this using `patch.object` if you have access to the object by accessing the class of the object:

```py
def test_no_foo():
    bar_mock = mock.PropertyMock()
    foo = Foo()
    with mock.patch.object(foo.__class__, "bar", bar_mock):
        bar_mock.side_effect = AttributeError('Boom!')
        with pytest.raises(AttributeError):
            foo.bar
```

Comment: Thanks for figuring that out, unfortunately the fotted path to the object will be different for different ppl (its not a constant), the class is a pluggable/swappble instance. I tried `with mock.patch.object(foo, 'bar'):` but it just says `AttributeError: can't set attribute`

Comment: You can try to patch the property via the class - I added another example in the answer.

Comment: Great thanks so much, I missed that important point!